# Write simple HTTP forwarding perl or php script to run as a proxy server

Tags: php, perl, proxy, cgi

I want to write either a perl (CGI) or php script on a server to behave like a proxy server. I want to be able to enter the hostname and port on firefox proxy settings (or IE, chrome, whatever) and then go to a site, and have my webserver forward the request to another server, and forward the response back to the client. This way, I am basically using my server as a proxy server. Is there a perl or php script that can do this? If so, what?

## Do not suggest anything along the lines of PHProxy or Glype.

#### I don't want a server that I go into with my browser and enter a URL to browse. That's a big NO-NO.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. It sounds to me like you need to look at something like squid (http://www.squid-cache.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CPAN module [HTTP::Proxy](http://search.cpan.org/~book/HTTP-Proxy-0.24/lib/HTTP/Proxy.pm) implements a simple HTTP proxy server that you can start and run out-of-the-box.

Comment: My server doesn't have HTTP::Proxy Installed.